# Users page could be more informative as to which reputation [range] is being shown

Tags: feature-request, users

I got caught out the other day when I visited the Users page (on ELL) for the first time. I expected to see Users listed with their total reputation, a sort of *High Scores table*, if you will. However, I failed to understand what I was seeing and fired off the following question to ELL Meta.

(I have quoted the original question in this format as I feel that it shows the train of thought of a *new visitor* to the site).

#### The question

> The [Users page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users) is quite clearly showing out of date reputations:
>
> [image: Out of date reputations on Users page]
>
> As one would expect, it happens on all pages, not just the first one.
>   Obviously, when you click on a user, the correct reputation is
>   displayed in the resulting user profile page.
>
> This issue must have been raised already, but I couldn't find a
>   question about it.
>
> I have checked this on two different browsers (Chrome and Firefox and
>   two different OSes (OS X 10.8.5 and Lubuntu 11).
>
> ---
>
> #### Update - My "bad"
>
> Thanks to [StoneyB](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) for the comment...
>
> > Note that there's a choice near the top for 'week month quarter year
> >     all'; it defaults to rep for the current month, not total rep. – 
> >     StoneyB
>
> Ah! Don't I feel like an idiot now..? ;-) Although I do wonder how
>   many other people have been caught out by this, upon their first
>   glance? Obviously, once you know, it is quite obvious. Would it not be
>   better to default to "All"? Although I can see that this would be a
>   matter of preference that would vary from person to person. Maybe have
>   a SE wide default that can be set on a per-user basis? Or default to
>   "All" for a new user and then remember the change in a cookie. (OK, I
>   have managed to bore even myself now)
>
> StoneyB's suggestion of a more prominent heading/title,
>
> > It'd be nice if the selection posted an appropriate title. –  StoneyB
>
> in lieu of a small highlighted button, would certainly go a long way
>   to alleviating the issue.

As this is a SE wide issue and not just ELL, the question has been migrated from SE.ELL Meta to SE Meta.

#### Summary

To sum up the two issues that I have:

1. Should the [Users page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users) first not default to *Total* reputation and
   then any subsequent selection of a specific time frame be recorded in a
   cookie?
2. Could there be a more prominent title/description?

The new title could be placed just below the *Users* heading saying something along the lines of "Reputation for the Week/Month/Year/All Time" or "Reputation for the Weekly/Monthly/Annual/Total Reputation", depending on the selection on the right, like so (please excuse the god awful font)

[image: Suggested subtitle for Users page]

Comment: Note that there's a choice near the top for 'week month quarter year all'; it defaults to rep for the current month, not total rep.

Comment: It'd be nice if the selection posted an appropriate title.

Comment: @stoney Agreed! Greenonline, I'd be happy to migrate this for you if you like. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd - Please do so. Thank you. BTW, I have quoted Stoney's comments in the question, so that they do not get lost in the migration. However, do you think that the question requires re-wording? As it currently stands it, especially the title, is a case of user error, rather than a feature request.

Comment: @greenonline Yeah, if you can reword it as a feature request and then ping me again that would be great :)

Comment: @WendiKidd - I think it is ready to be migrated now. Thank you. :-)

Comment: As for **why** the default view is _month_, I suppose the designers of the system figured most people would generally want to know who was being productive in recent weeks, not all time. Or, as the famous English expression goes: [*What have you done for me lately?*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=What%20have%20you%20done%20for%20me%20lately)

Comment: This still bugs me whenever I visit that page.  I can figure it out, but for a while I'm always confused because I don't visit that page very often and I forget.

Comment: I appreciate you bringing this up! It's been bugging me too, and since I'm almost a "seasoned user," especially on GL, I figured there was something I was missing but was too embarrassed to ask about it! Not until I saw this did I even notice those choices. I keep forgetting that many SE pages have different tabs, and we just need to look for them! Hang in, and please don't stop asking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the existing default (current *month*) is probably the best of the available possibilities. Granted, if ***last 28 days*** was available I'd prefer that, but we are where we are.

"Seasoned" users will obviously soon realize they can easily vary the time-frame, so it doesn't really matter much how the display *starts* (though one could argue it would be a nice touch if the UI defaulted to *whatever you selected last time*).

But I suggest what should matter more to *new* users (and would often interest me personally) is ***currently active***, community-endorsed users. It's not usually very important to know about high-rep users who've not visited the site (or *contributed upvoteable content*) for months or even years.

The current default can be "skewed" for the first few hours/days at the beginning of a month (not everyone is *constantly* active), but mostly it does reflect the "current" situation. So my position is...

> [“**It ain't broke, so don't fix it!**”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20ain%27t%20broke%2C%20so%20don%27t%20fix%20it%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)