# Why questions are sorted by the total number of votes and not by the number of up-votes?

Tags: support, sorting

I stumbled over this question on ask Ubuntu:

[Avconv warning while downloading YouTube video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563245/avconv-warning-while-downloading-youtube-video)

And noticed that a answer with overall score of 1 one is above an answer with an overall score of 3.

I expanded the votes I see that it has 4 upvotes and 3 downvotes and this is why is above the one scored with 3.

Why questions are sorted by the total number of votes and not by the number of up-votes? Is this on all the sites? Is it a bug?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the votes tab of the answer? http://askubuntu.com/questions/563245/avconv-warning-while-downloading-youtube-video?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you were sorting by *oldest*:

> [image: Answers sorted by oldest]

If you sort by *votes* then the answers are listed in the expected order.

Comment: Oh ... my, i guess to much new year partying :D

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu - No worries, I have been caught out by those tiny sort tabs before, see [Users page could be more informative as to which reputation range is being shown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251347/users-page-could-be-more-informative-as-to-which-reputation-range-is-being-sho)... :-)

Comment: @Eduard Happens to many - the real "problem" is that the site remembers the last sort for good, never forgetting it. So if clicked by mistake, that mistake sticks. :)